# Substracting End and Start times to find difference in minutes

Tags: vb.net, time

So I need to see if there is at least 10 minutes between times to make my operator true or not so it knows to alert or not below is the code in VB.net

```
        Dim LessThanTen As Double

    Dim CheckTimeBegin As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txttimebegin.Text)
    Dim CheckTimeEnd As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(txttimeend.Text)



    Dim Duration As TimeSpan = CheckTimeEnd - CheckTimeBegin

    If Duration.TotalMinutes < 10 Then
        LessThanTen = True
    Else
        LessThanTen = False
    End If
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I fixed it with ParseExact my apologizes

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it

```
        Dim LessThanTen As Double

    Dim Startt = DateTime.ParseExact(txttimebegin.Text, "h:mm:tt", Nothing)
    Dim Endt = DateTime.ParseExact(txttimeend.Text, "h:mm:tt", Nothing)

    Dim Duration As TimeSpan = Startt - Endt

    If Duration.TotalMinutes < 10 Then
        LessThanTen = True
    Else
        LessThanTen = False
    End If
```